# Проблема с установкой QT Creater

Tags: qtcreator

Долго пользовался Qt Creater, после переустановки системы попытался установит, но не получается.

Скачал с оф. сайта программу для установки, но при запуске возникают проблемы.

Сначала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто сталквался с таким?

p.s. Сommercial версия не доступна для скачивания

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все заразрешилось само, странно, что так долго они решали данный вопрос, порядка месяца

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю вы пытались установить QT через online инсталлер, но по какой-то причине не могли достучаться до их серверов.
Для таких случаев на сайте QT в разделе загрузок лежат оффлайн версии установщиков.